# How can I give Drupal 8 access to config files outside the web root?

Tags: php, apache, drupal, drupal-8

I just jumped into Drupal 8, and I'm having trouble enabling file-based config in my project. I am using these instructions: https://www.drupal.org/node/2416555

I've followed all the steps, but every time I try to make a config change, I get the following error:

```
Drupal\Core\Config\StorageException: Failed to create config directory 
./../config/active in Drupal\Core\Config\FileStorage->ensureStorage() 
(line 72 of /Users/bbalan/Sites/d8project/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/FileStorage.php).
```

I think there's something wrong with the paths in my settings.php. The instructions say to use a path outside the web root, probably for security reasons. Here's what I have:

```
$config_directories = array(
    CONFIG_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY  => './../config/active',
    CONFIG_STAGING_DIRECTORY => './../config/staging',
    CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY    => './../config/sync',
);
```

I set all the config directory permissions to 777, and the active/staging/sync directories have already been created manually (also with 777). Here are the contents of my project folder:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 bbalan  staff   18046  8 Aug 15:22 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--   1 bbalan  staff    4787  8 Aug 15:22 README.md
-rw-r--r--   1 bbalan  staff    2299  8 Aug 17:35 composer.json
-rw-r--r--   1 bbalan  staff  206302  8 Aug 17:35 composer.lock
drwxrwxrwx   6 bbalan  staff     204  8 Aug 15:36 config
drwxr-xr-x   4 bbalan  staff     136  8 Aug 15:22 drush
-rw-r--r--   1 bbalan  staff     481  8 Aug 15:22 phpunit.xml.dist
drwxr-xr-x   3 bbalan  staff     102  8 Aug 15:22 scripts
drwxr-xr-x  42 bbalan  staff    1428  8 Aug 17:36 vendor
drwxr-xr-x  19 bbalan  staff     646  8 Aug 17:23 web
```

This is a Drupal 8.1.8 install built with Composer from instructions at https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project . All the Drupal site files are in `/web`. Here's my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName drupal-8.local
    ServerAlias drupal-8.local
    DocumentRoot /Users/bbalan/Sites/d8project/web/
    <Directory /Users/bbalan/Sites/d8project/web/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas? Everything works if I move the `/config` dir to a location in the web root (for example, `/sites/default/files/config`), but this seems unsafe and counter to the instructions.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend having the config directories as 777. 755 is a much better approach as it lets the owner and group members read and write. You can also try 775 if you want to allow group members to execute. Also, make sure that the web servers user is part of that group. Apache typically uses www-data. I would also recommend moving your config directory to `sites/default/sync`.

```
$config_directories = array(
    CONFIG_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY  => 'sites/default/config/active',
    CONFIG_STAGING_DIRECTORY => 'sites/default/config/staging',
    CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY    => 'sites/default/config/sync',
);
```

Make sure those directories exists and the web server is part of the group `staff`.

The other thing I would check is Drupal's status and see what it tells you there.

Comment: Thank you! I moved the config directories, set permissions to 775, updated `settings.php` and added Apache user `_www` to group `staff` - that did the trick.